# How to Edit Permission Declaration Form?

Tags: android, google-play-console

this is regarding new permission changes. So, in the previous build, we needed SMS and call permission so we filled a form while uploading to play store and those permissions were in the manifest.  But, now we have removed that permission. It is still showing that older declared permission. There is no way to edit declaration form that we don't have those permissions now.
And it wants us to select a core functionality.
this is the error we are seeing:

```
Declare sensitive permissions
All apps requesting to use sensitive permissions, such as SMS or Call Log permission groups, must complete the Permissions Declaration Form. Failing to report any app functionality that uses these permissions can lead to app suspension.
We don't allow these permissions to be used for contact prioritization, affinity profiles, or social graphs.
If you're using SMS or Call Log permissions for account verification, sharing content, or initiating a text message or phone call, you can use alternative methods to get the same functionality. Learn more
Previously declared permissions (3 permissions)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to edit Declaration form. What is perhaps happening here is you are directly releasing (permission free app) to Production Mode while your Internal Release or Alpha or Beta still has an apk which requires permission. PlayStore Review mechanism does not distinguish between mode of APKs and keep rejecting updates if it finds an active APK which has sensitive permissions. I would suggest you to first upload your new APK to Internal Test and then promote it to Aplha/Beta and then to Production. This will solve your problem and you would not be getting the Declaration form again.
[Get all the tracks to the same version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMaCu.png)